# React Native FlatList - How can I leave space for a button underneath?

Tags: react-native, layout

I'm one week new to React Native and I'm trying to put a button at the bottom of a FlatList.

I've got the FlatList working properly but if I put my button like the below (greatly simplified) pseudo-code then it appears right at the bottom of all the items in the FlatList.

What I want is for the button to always be on the bottom of the screen and for the FlatList to scroll above it.

I'm thinking I might need a wrapping container and then set flex on the FlatList and the Button but I can't quite get there.

```
<Container>

  <Content>
      <FlatList
          ...working FlatList goes here...
      />

      <Button block onPress={() => Actions.filters()}>
        <Text>Filter results</Text>
    </Button>

  </Content>
```

In the interest of brevity I took all the attributes out of the FlatList, but it's working and not the problem.  I just want to stick that button onto the bottom of the screen and for it to stay there.

What's the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one view for the FlatList and one for the Button, like this:

```
<Container>

    <Content>
        <View style={{flex: 3}}>
            <FlatList
                ...working FlatList goes here...
            />
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}
            <Button block onPress={() => Actions.filters()}>
                <Text>Filter results</Text>
            </Button>
        </View>

    </Content>
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work though.  The FlatList still scrolls past the end of the device screen and the Button is placed below it (off screen until you scroll all the way to the end).

Comment: Try removing the `Content` tag

Comment: That `Content` tag comes from NativeBase?

Answer (score 6):

FlatList now provides `ListFooterComponent`

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listfootercomponent

Comment: but keeps on the bottom of all items :( if the list is too large, then I cannot see the button unless I scroll down throught all the items and that's really bad